# Bundling the JRE with a Java application

Tags: java

I have created an exe with a launch4j Ant script and build.xml file. I want to bundle the JRE in my application and have to distribute it to clients. How do I do this?

Comment: Make sure you abide by Sun's agreement for redistributing the JRE: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/README.html#redistribution - it shouldn't be a problem, but you should be aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, just bundle everything under `$JAVA_HOME/jre` into your distribution (presumably a `Zip`/`TAR` file) and then have your scripts reference that (i.e. use the `java` executable under `$JRE_HOME/bin` to run your java program).

Remember that if you do this, you will have to deliver different distributions for different target platforms (Windows,OSX, linux etc) and architectures (or one bloated *uber-distribution* of course, but no one will thank you for that!).

Answer (score 2):

This works great... if you want your program to run on just a single version of a specific OS.

Generally, though, bundling a JRE is a bad idea.  Even on Windows, there are three versions of the JRE: one for x86, one for x86-64, and one for Itanium.  Even if Sun does make it hard to find the 64-bit versions, they still exist.

The 64-bit versions of Java for Windows are actually on [java.sun.com](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jre-6u16-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer), but not java.com.