# Any way to run an exe made from jar using exe4j from another computer?

Tags: java, exe4j

I've made a little GUI program to enter contents then send "javamail" to my email. I have to import many jar libraries from javamail-1.4.5 and then I build it (shift + f11) to jar, then use exe4j to make it exe (also add all the jars from the libraries in the /dist/lib) and version of jre from 1.5 to 1.7 (I'm using 1.7 to make this app). It works smoothly on my computer but when I give the exe to others computer. It said:

"**No JVM could be found on your system. Please define EXE4J_JAVA_HOME to point to an installed 32-bit JDK or JRE or download a JRE from www.java.com**"

I think they must install the JDK in order to be able to run the app. But it may be confusing to many of my friends who don't know about computing. Is there anyway can they use that send-javamail-app without asking them to install the JDK?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English!

Comment: You don't need jdk, you need JRE, jsut be sure target machine has one (most modern PC have it anyway) and set EXE4J_JAVA_HOME accordingly

Comment: have a read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071133/how-to-bundle-a-jre-with-launch4j

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple.

After you have done basic steps as set the name, icon, etc, in step number 6 JRE is where the magic happens:

1. Click Advanced Options and select Search sequence

[image]

2. Click to add new item + and select directory

[image]

3. Select your jre directory, it must be a relative path

[image]

4. Put your new item at the first position in list
   [image]

After that what you have to do is release your exe with the jre directory together, to do that usually I use [Inno Setup Compiler](http://www.jrsoftware.org/) to create a installer.

Comment: Even though it's a little bit late but I'll take a look at this when possible. Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle the JRE with your product, this is the best way you can achieve without bothering your buddies. The size of your application will increase.

JRE is required to run any java application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to do that? How to bundle the JRE with my app?

Comment: in exe4j make new media file and use bundled JRE.

Comment: I still have no idea how to get the bundled JRE. And by the way... I don't see anywhere I can make new media... does it have any other name?

Answer (score 0):

Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is required to run the Java application. In order to install JRE on a computer without Java installed, you must either bundle it (put it inside your application), or ask your friends to download JRE.
I don't know exactly how to bundle JRE, but the question [Bundling the JRE with a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357153/bundling-the-jre-with-a-java-application) can probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my personal project Java Customization Builder can help you, it analyzes the classes used by your program, and slim these classes from jars, and it also analyzes jvm files used by your program. Then it make an executable file and pack200 the jre runtime and your program.

JCB Project Introduction:

Java Customization Builder is a tool which customizes your java application and JRE.

It is a java application building tool enabling you to generate a very small java archive package which has a slimmed jre. For the swing application, the archive is less than 5M, for the SWT application, the archive is less than 3M usually. And the customed java applicaton can run on the Windows which doesn't install a JRE, and be loaded by an executable.

JCB project page: http://jcb.sourceforge.net

Comment: Can you give me a link for a tutorial? I've been clicking and after compiling I have a exe file with 2 folders, and the exe can't run without those folder... I'm kinda confuse now