# Javafx application built in JDK 7 doesn't run with Java 8

Tags: javafx, java-8, java-7

I've developed a JavaFx application using JDK 7, but now that Java 8 was released, my client unistalled jre 7 and installed jre 8, and now the app is not running anymore:

[image]

I'm not sure but jre8 should not be compatible with previous versions of java? At least the last one ?

What can I do to solve this?

**EDITED**: I'm using exe4j to distribute my app as .exe

Comment: possibly a 32 vs 64 bit issue? Is it run from a browser?

Comment: It's a desktop app, and it's not a 32 vs 64 issue I've tested it.

Comment: What deployment method are you using? Is it possible to try to run the application from the command line? That way you should be able to see any error messages. And have you tested with Java 8 on your own machine?

Comment: @javaHunter did u try to read the question ?

Comment: We had same problem when we were developing fx application using jdk7 and we had to switch to jdk8. But we faced some gui related problems only (FXML files were used). Is it possible to redistribute your application by compiling it with jdk8? Is your client using .jar file or .exe?

Comment: @Muskan I'm using exe4j to distribute as .exe. Compiling with jdk 8 is an option, but I was trying to figure out other resolution to the problem. You can apply your hint as an answer, it's a real possibility

Comment: I haven't used exe4j but i have used launch4j. I don't think it makes any difference though. Instead of depending upon client's JRE you can send your own JRE along with your application. And if you are using .exe, its even easier. I have made a blog on this topic and i will post it as an answer. I hope it will help you and forgive my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muskan answers was very helpful because gave me a hint to bundle a jre with my application.

Actually I've not used launch4j instead I've used exe4j, which is very similar but I've used before.

If you decide to use this approach you can find [step by step here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343077/any-way-to-run-an-exe-made-from-jar-using-exe4j-from-another-computer/27410832#27410832)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link http://progressinjava.blogspot.com/2014/12/using-applications-own-jre-and-not.html 
It uses launch4j to create .exe file and show you how to distribute your application with jre.